# {exp:search:keywords} doesn't show keywords used in search

Tags: simple-search

I'm using EE native simple search and in the results template have the following at the opening tag:

```
{exp:search:search_results limit="16"}
{if count=="1"}
<h1>Search Results</h1>
<p>You searched for <strong>{exp:search:keywords}</strong>.</p>
<ul class="product-grid">
{/if}
<li>...</li>
```

But the results shows like this...

[image: Search results screenshot]

The string looks to be the same for each search with results and doesn't match the URL string.

The no_results page seems to output correctly...

[image: No results search output]

Anyone else come across this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've seen this before when `{exp:search:keywords}` is used twice in the same template. Try adding `random` to the tag so that it's not cached by the template parser:

```
{exp:search:keywords random}
```

Comment: Thanks Derek, that seems to do the trick. Not seen this in the docs anywhere, so good to know :-). Interestingly, the tag is only used once in the template though.

Answer (score 0):

When I've seen problems like this before it's been a parse order issue; perhaps the unnecessary quotes around "1" in the conditional are throwing things off? Try `{if count==1}` and see what happens.